# Can a video and a document be stored in the same library

Tags: 2010, document, library, video

I creating a training portal in Sharepoint 2010 for users to go and help themselves to solutions to problems and how-to documents. We are also creating some simulation videos as an alternative option to documents. Our aim is to have them both appearing alongside each other.
For instance, when you expand the group within the library and see the list of documents "Howtodothis.docx" and "Howtodothis.mp4" will appear next to each other.
I realise I could do this with an asset library but I also want to include content types with the library, so that when people create a new document it matches the template we are creating.

And ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can.

You'd want to create a document library with no default content type specified and then create and add your content types to the library by setting the Manage Content Types option to Yes in the Advanced Settings of the library.

Then you'd just need to figure out how you would group things together in your library so that the docx and mp4 file show up together.  This could be achieved by having a shared field in the content types to group on.